# Hibernate and c3p0: unexplained why client is unable to communicate after some time

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

Running the following code...

```
    Session session;

    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();;

        // Query the DB for a list of sms to be sent
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Sdnchurch");            
        list = query.list();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // Manage exception
    }
    finally {
        if (session != null) 
            session.close();
    }
```

...after some time I get the following exception:

```
failureorg.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement
```

This exception starts being generated after I use my client for a time longer than the WAIT_TIMEOUT configured in mySql.

This is my C3p0 configuration for Hibernate in the hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">200</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">7200</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">0</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod">3600</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
```

As you can see, I'm also testing the connection. So I can't really see what's going wrong.

How can I fix this? Here's the stack trace:

```
11:20:59,547 INFO  [stdout] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) Hibernate: select sdnchurc0_.CHURCH_ID as CHURCH1_0_, sdnchurc0_.CHURCH_NAME as CHURCH2_0_ from Msdchurch sdnchurc0_

11:20:59,549 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
11:20:59,549 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed by the driver.
11:20:59,549 INFO  [uk.co.nisma.sdn.dao.MsdchurchDaoImpl] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) Rolling back...
11:20:59,549 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) uk.co.nisma.sdn.exception.MsdwardException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement

11:20:59,550 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at uk.co.nisma.sdn.dao.MsdchurchDaoImpl.getListHospitals(MsdchurchDaoImpl.java:53)

11:20:59,550 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at uk.co.nisma.sdn.WardDetailsImpl.getWardDetails(WardDetailsImpl.java:25)

11:20:59,551 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

11:20:59,551 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)

11:20:59,551 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

11:20:59,551 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

11:20:59,551 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandlerJSE.java:111)

11:20:59,552 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker._invokeInternal(JBossWSInvoker.java:181)

11:20:59,552 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:127)

11:20:59,552 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)

11:20:59,552 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)

11:20:59,553 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)

11:20:59,553 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)

11:20:59,553 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)

11:20:59,553 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)

11:20:59,553 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)

11:20:59,554 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)

11:20:59,554 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)

11:20:59,554 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:91)

11:20:59,554 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:169)

11:20:59,555 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:87)

11:20:59,555 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)

11:20:59,555 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)

11:20:59,555 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)

11:20:59,556 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:135)

11:20:59,556 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140)

11:20:59,556 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

11:20:59,556 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)

11:20:59,556 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

11:20:59,557 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

11:20:59,557 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

11:20:59,557 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)

11:20:59,557 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)

11:20:59,558 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

11:20:59,558 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

11:20:59,558 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)

11:20:59,558 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:505)

11:20:59,559 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:445)

11:20:59,559 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)

11:20:59,559 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

11:20:59,560 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement

11:20:59,560 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:67)

11:20:59,560 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)

11:20:59,560 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)

11:20:59,561 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:188)

11:20:59,561 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:159)

11:20:59,561 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1859)

11:20:59,561 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1836)

11:20:59,562 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1816)

11:20:59,562 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:900)

11:20:59,562 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)

11:20:59,562 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2526)

11:20:59,562 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2512)

11:20:59,563 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2342)

11:20:59,563 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2337)

11:20:59,563 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:495)

11:20:59,563 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:356)

11:20:59,570 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)

11:20:59,570 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1269)

11:20:59,570 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)

11:20:59,570 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at uk.co.nisma.sdn.dao.MsdchurchDaoImpl.getListHospitals(MsdchurchDaoImpl.java:47)

11:20:59,570 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   ... 39 more

11:20:59,571 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed by the driver.

11:20:59,571 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

11:20:59,571 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)

11:20:59,572 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

11:20:59,572 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)

11:20:59,572 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)

11:20:59,572 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)

11:20:59,573 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)

11:20:59,573 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)

11:20:59,573 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)

11:20:59,573 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1160)

11:20:59,573 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1147)

11:20:59,574 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4224)

11:20:59,574 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4190)

11:20:59,574 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:161)

11:20:59,574 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:182)

11:20:59,575 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   ... 55 more

11:20:59,575 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
11:20:59,575 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) 
11:20:59,575 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) The last packet successfully received from the server was 70,060 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.

11:20:59,575 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

11:20:59,576 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)

11:20:59,576 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

11:20:59,576 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)

11:20:59,576 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)

11:20:59,576 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)

11:20:59,577 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3052)

11:20:59,577 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2938)

11:20:59,577 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3481)

11:20:59,577 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)

11:20:59,577 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)

11:20:59,578 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)

11:20:59,578 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)

11:20:59,578 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2228)

11:20:59,578 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:56)

11:20:59,580 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2040)

11:20:59,580 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1837)

11:20:59,580 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   ... 52 more

11:20:59,580 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1) Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

11:20:59,581 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)

11:20:59,581 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)

11:20:59,581 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)

11:20:59,589 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:113)

11:20:59,589 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:160)

11:20:59,589 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:188)

11:20:59,589 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2494)

11:20:59,590 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2949)

11:20:59,590 ERROR [stderr] (ajp--0.0.0.0-8009-1)   ... 62 more
```

Comment: c3p0's Connection testing would have prevented mysql timeouts from bothering you. but, though you show some c3p0 settings above, your app does not appear to be using c3p0 or any other pool. your stacktrace goes directly from hibernate code to mysql driver code, without intermediation by Connection pool proxy. your challenge is to figure out why your app isn't using c3p0, why your configuration of C3P0ConnectionProvider isn't taking. [do you see in your logs initialization of a c3p0 pool? c3p0 dumps config data @ INFO on initialization; check for that.]

Comment: I found this: c3p0 properties were encountered, but the org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider provider class was not found on the classpath; these properties are going to be ignored